# How convert a string to date in SQLite query? (WatermelonDB)

Tags: sqlite

I'm using watermelonDB in my application, however watermelon save Date as number in Database.

I intend get all items on month or year, howerver I can't compare filter's date with the date of database.

```
`SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE 
${byYear
      ? `date(${dateString}, 'start of year') = date(created_at, 'start of year')`
      : `date(${dateString}, 'start of month') = date(created_at, 'start of month') AND 
           date(${dateString}, 'start of year') = datetime(created_at, 'start of year')`
}`
```

Is there a option to transform `created_at` in "YYYY-MM-DD" with SQLite methods?

Comment: What does this number that is used for dates represent?

Comment: new Date().getTime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the timestamps that are stored in the table are integer numbers that represent milliseconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

You can convert them to readable text dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` with:

```
date(created_at / 1000, 'unixepoch')
```

or

```
date(created_at / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

The division by `1000` strips off the milliseconds.

You can apply other modifiers too, like `'start of year'` or `'start of month'`:

```
date(created_at / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime', 'start of year')
```